# Как на письме передать произношение слова "спец(?)яльно"?

Tags: орфография

Какой там, в скобочках, должен стоять знак?

Comment: Если в шутку, то твёрдый знак или буква "и", но ближайшее "нормативное" слово с таким же произношением пишется слитно, без знаков и трансформации "я" в "а" : **спецяхта** - подобно тому, как пишется **дезинформация** (без всяких "ы" и разделителей).

Comment: Саша, есть варианты... А какие при передаче точно расслышанного слова могут быть шутки? Слух такой особый есть - фонетический. При этом может не быть музыкального.

Comment: @Alex_ander пожалуйста, не используйте комментарии для ответов.

Comment: Это не ответ, а попытка выяснить, с какой целью нужно записать слово с отклонением от произносительной нормы - от этого зависит выбор написания.

Comment: @Alex_ander вопрос здесь совсем не выражен внешне, а ответ дан: «твердый знак иди буква „и"». Впрочем, и некоторый запрос на ответ в вашем комментарии присутствует.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем я поняла вопрос, потом увидела ваше "спецьяльно".

Так можно записать, **считая мягкий знак разделительным**, тогда после Ц будет произноситься звук ЙА. Разделительный Ь пишется как после твердых, так и после мягких согласныХ, мягкость он не обозначает.

**Примечание:** Правило произношения слова "специальный" (на всякий случай, для справок). Мне кажется, что звук И многие пропускают.

**Две гласные при встрече должны произноситься.** https://studfiles.net/preview/5809938/page:7/

В современной речи часто встречается ошибка – **«съедание» гласного звука**, то есть при произнесении слов вместо двух рядом стоящих гласных произносится только один. **Эта ошибка** связана не столько с незнанием орфоэпических правил, сколько с небрежностью и торопливостью речи.

Comment: Жасминчик! Как могла ты заподозрить, что я что-нито можу произносить неправильно? Мне интересно фиксировать точно особенности произношения! Разделительный так разделительный, я на всё согласная.